# What's the word for the simpler version of something complex

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

At times we say this but just now it's completely blank. Say there's a complex definition for something, which we need to explain in simple words so that a person who's not an expert in that area can understand it, we would say:

> Give me the _____ version of this

(the same definition in simple easily understandable words)

Comment: As in the relationship of a *map* to the actual *territory*? A simplified *model*? A *sketch*? An *outline*?

Comment: *In English, please.* Particularly if the complex version is full of jargon.

Comment: *Simple English* (think of Simple English Wikipedia), *lowbrow, bottom line, takeaway, first approximation, layman's, dumbed down, idiot-proof, for idiots*.

Answer (score 1):

Got it from one of my friends.. 'Layman's terms' is the phrase I was looking for.

***In layman's terms*** -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_layman's_terms)

> (idiomatic) Phrased simply, without jargon.
>   *"Okay, let me explain this in layman's terms."*

Answer (score 0):

A less-formal version is ***the CliffsNotes version***, referencing the [CliffsNotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CliffsNotes) series of study guides, and referring to a condensed and simplified form of explanation.

Another term you could use would be ***in a nutshell***, suggesting a brief explanation that hits the key points.

Answer (score 0):

The direct application to your sentence would be most likely be *simplified*. But we could probably do better!

A nice, juicy word for this would be to make the information *digestible*.

Digestible via [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/digestible)

> (of information) easy to understand or follow. ‘her books convey
>   philosophical issues in a lucid and digestible form’

Another nice word to use in the place of simple could be *exoteric*, which continues to fit in the theme of lightening information consumption.

Exoteric via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exoteric)

> 1. suitable for or communicated to the general public.
> 2. not belonging, limited, or pertaining to the inner or select circle, as of disciples or intimates.
> 3. popular; simple; commonplace.

If you boil down the complexity of Exoteric and combine it with the lightness of digestible, you'd be led to *lucid*.

Lucid via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lucid)

> easily understood; completely intelligible or comprehensible:
>   "She returns with a “Life in the 50s” memoir that moms can relate to,
>   thanks to her lucid, plainspoken observations."

Synonyms: Coherent, Clear, intelligible, comprehensible, plain, simple, unambiguous, absorbable, graspable, fathomable.